# Passing Parameter on ATMEGA128?

Tags: avr, atmega

I don't understand on passing parameter on ATMEGA128 and AVR Studio 6,
I tested this function and working find

```
lcd_cmd()
{
            PORTD = 0xFF;
            _delay_ms(100);
            PORTD = 0x00;
            _delay_ms(100);

            en=0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            en=1;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rs=0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rs=1;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rw=0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rw=1;
            _delay_ms(100);    
}
main()
{
 lcd_cmd();
}
```

D0-D4 are appearing
![enter image description here][1]
but by the time I put parameter to be passed, it doesn't work

```
lcd_cmd(unsigned char data_cmd)
{
            PORTD = data_cmd;
            _delay_ms(100);
            PORTD = data_cmd;
            _delay_ms(100);

            en=0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            en=1;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rs=0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rs=1;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rw=0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            rw=1;
            _delay_ms(100);
}

main() {
   while(1) {
     lcd_cmd(0xFF);
     _delay_ms(100);
     lcd_cmd(0x00);
   }
}
```

as you can see D0-D4 are missing but rw,rs,and en are working
![enter image description here][2]

What do I miss here ? It's very strange for me....
Any experiences , shares or knowledges will be very appreciated,

Here's the complete code, please let me know what I miss here ???

```
    #include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// structure to allow bit field operations, name conversions: PORTA.0 -> PORT_A.b0  PORTB.7 -> PORT_B.b7
typedef struct{ uint8_t b0:1;
                uint8_t b1:1;
                uint8_t b2:1;
                uint8_t b3:1;
                uint8_t b4:1;
                uint8_t b5:1;
                uint8_t b6:1;
                uint8_t b7:1; } bits;

// define all the ports of your microcontroller, add more ports depending on the available mcu ports
#define PORT_A (* (volatile bits *) &PORTA)
#define PIN_A (* (volatile bits *) &PINA)
#define DDR_A (* (volatile bits *) &DDRA)

#define PORT_B (* (volatile bits *) &PORTB)
#define PIN_B (* (volatile bits *) &PINB)
#define DDR_B (* (volatile bits *) &DDRB)

//Mention Clock frequency here
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000 

#define lcd_data_pin PORTD

#define en PORT_A.b0
#define rs PORT_A.b1
#define rw PORT_A.b2




void lcd_init();
void lcd_data(unsigned char data1);
void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd);
void lcd_control(unsigned char cmdordata);
void lcd_string(unsigned char *str);


void lcd_init(){

    lcd_cmd(0x02);      
    lcd_cmd(0x28);      
    lcd_cmd(0x0C);
    lcd_cmd(0x06);
    lcd_cmd(0x80);

}

void lcd_data(unsigned char data1)
{

    lcd_data_pin = data1;
    lcd_control(2);


}

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd){

    lcd_data_pin = cmd & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(1);

    lcd_data_pin = (cmd << 4) & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(1);


}

void lcd_control(unsigned char cmdordata){

    if(cmdordata == 1){
        en=1;
        rs=0;
        rw=0;
        _delay_ms(1);       
        en=0;
    }
    else if(cmdordata == 2){
        en=1;
        rs=1;
        rw=0;
        _delay_ms(1);
        en=0;
    }
}

void lcd_string(unsigned char *str){

    while(*str){
        lcd_data(*str++);       
    }

}




int main(){

    DDRA = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0xFF;

    lcd_init();
    lcd_data('A');


    while(1){

        lcd_string("Working?");

    }

    return (0);
}
```

so the right one will be:

```
void lcd_data(unsigned char data1)
{

    lcd_data_pin = data1 & 0xF0;;
    lcd_control(2);

    lcd_data_pin = (data1<< 4) & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(2);


}

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd){

    lcd_data_pin = cmd & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(1);

    lcd_data_pin = (cmd << 4) & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(1);
```

}

I tested on ATMEGA32, and it's allright, is it related with ATMEGA128 configuration ??? Latest code :

```
 #include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// structure to allow bit field operations, name conversions: PORTA.0 -> PORT_A.b0  PORTB.7 -> PORT_B.b7
typedef struct{ uint8_t b0:1;
                uint8_t b1:1;
                uint8_t b2:1;
                uint8_t b3:1;
                uint8_t b4:1;
                uint8_t b5:1;
                uint8_t b6:1;
                uint8_t b7:1; } bits;

// define all the ports of your microcontroller, add more ports depending on the available mcu ports
#define PORT_D (* (volatile bits *) &PORTD)
#define PIN_D (* (volatile bits *) &PIND)
#define DDR_D (* (volatile bits *) &DDRD)

#define PORT_G (* (volatile bits *) &PORTG)
#define PIN_G (* (volatile bits *) &PING)
#define DDR_G (* (volatile bits *) &DDRG)

//Mention Clock frequency here
//#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000 

#define lcd_data_pin PORTA

#define en PORT_D.b0
#define rs PORT_D.b1
#define rw PORT_D.b2


void lcd_init();
void lcd_data(unsigned char data1);
void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd);
void lcd_control(unsigned char cmdordata);
void lcd_string(unsigned char *str);


void lcd_init(){

    lcd_cmd(0x30);
    _delay_ms(100);      
    lcd_cmd(0x38);
    _delay_ms(100);      
    lcd_cmd(0x0F);
    _delay_ms(100);
    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    _delay_ms(100);

}

void lcd_data(unsigned char data1)
{


    lcd_data_pin = data1;// & 0x0F;
        en=1;
        rs=1;
        rw=0;
        _delay_ms(10);
        en=0;

}

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd){
    lcd_data_pin = cmd ;
        en=1;
        rs=0;
        rw=0;
        _delay_ms(10);       
        en=0;

}



void lcd_string(unsigned char *str){

    while(*str){
        lcd_data(*str++);       
    }

}




int main(){

    DDR_D.b0 = 1;
    DDR_D.b1 = 1;
    DDR_D.b2 = 1;
    DDRA = 0xFF;

    lcd_init();


    while(1){
      _delay_ms (200);
        lcd_cmd(0x80);//put the cursor into the first row
        _delay_ms (300);
        lcd_cmd(0x01);//Clear display
        _delay_ms (300);
        lcd_cmd(0xC0);//goto second row
        _delay_ms (300); 
       lcd_cmd(0x01); //Clear display

       lcd_string("HELLO ATMEGA32");

    }

    return (0);
}
```

I used this code and can display until init but can not display character A
Video :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbL6GBVkWuU
The code (I'm not passing parameter at all and it works ):

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// structure to allow bit field operations, name conversions: PORTA.0 -> PORT_A.b0  PORTB.7 -> PORT_B.b7
typedef struct{ uint8_t b0:1;
                uint8_t b1:1;
                uint8_t b2:1;
                uint8_t b3:1;
                uint8_t b4:1;
                uint8_t b5:1;
                uint8_t b6:1;
                uint8_t b7:1; } bits;

// define all the ports of your microcontroller, add more ports depending on the available mcu ports
#define PORT_D (* (volatile bits *) &PORTD)
#define PIN_D (* (volatile bits *) &PIND)
#define DDR_D (* (volatile bits *) &DDRD)

#define PORT_G (* (volatile bits *) &PORTG)
#define PIN_G (* (volatile bits *) &PING)
#define DDR_G (* (volatile bits *) &DDRG)

//Mention Clock frequency here
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000 

#define lcd_data_pin PORTA

#define en PORT_D.b0
#define rs PORT_D.b1
#define rw PORT_D.b2





lcd_init()
{
      lcd_data_pin = 0x30;

       en = 1;
       rs = 0;
       rw = 0;
       _delay_ms(10);
      en = 0;

//next command
       _delay_ms(100);

      lcd_data_pin = 0x38;

       en = 1;
       rs = 0;
       rw = 0;
       _delay_ms(10);
      en = 0;
    _delay_ms(100);

      lcd_data_pin = 0x0F;

       en = 1;
       rs = 0;
       rw = 0;
       _delay_ms(10);
      en = 0;

//next command
       _delay_ms(100);

      lcd_data_pin = 0x80;

       en = 1;
       rs = 0;
       rw = 0;
       _delay_ms(10);
      en = 0;

      } 
  lcd_clear()
{
    lcd_data_pin = 0x80;//put the cursor into the first row
     en = 1;
       rs = 0;
       rw = 0;
       _delay_ms(10);
      en = 0;
        _delay_ms (300);

    lcd_data_pin = 0xC0;//put the cursor into the first row
     en = 1;
       rs = 0;
       rw = 0;
       _delay_ms(10);
      en = 0;
        _delay_ms (300);

}
void lcd_data()
{

       lcd_data_pin = 0x41;// & 0x0F;
        en=1;
        rs=1;
        rw=0;
        _delay_ms(10);
        en=0;

}



int main(){

    DDR_D.b0 = 1;
    DDR_D.b1 = 1;
    DDR_D.b2 = 1;
    DDRA = 0xFF;



    lcd_init();

    while(1){
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_data();
        _delay_ms(1000); 

    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the direction of your ports? It looks to me as though there must be more code. You are not passing a port address, so the FAQ you linked to is not relevant.

Comment: In the second variant do you really want to set PORTD to the same value twice in a row? You won't get the transitions like in the first diagram when you go from 0xFF to 0x00.

Comment: You are not passing the port as a parameter, so this isn't relevant. Passing a port as a parameter is when your function doesn't know which port to write to (`PORTD`, `PORTB`, `PORTC`, etc), and the port is passed as a parameter to such function. You are trying to pass the _value_ to write to the port. Like others have said, make sure that `DDRD` is set correctly (for instance `DDRD=0xFF;`). Also, even when relevant, it doesn't help to paste entire sections of FAQs: better to just link to those. Especially when such text lacks any formatting in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I need to do to make your code compile (on avr-gcc) and functional:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

bool en;
bool rs;
bool rw;

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char data_cmd)
{
        PORTD = data_cmd;
        _delay_ms(100);
        PORTD = data_cmd;
        _delay_ms(100);

        en=0;
        _delay_ms(100);
        en=1;
        _delay_ms(100);
        rs=0;
        _delay_ms(100);
        rs=1;
        _delay_ms(100);
        rw=0;
        _delay_ms(100);
        rw=1;
        _delay_ms(100);
}

int main() {
   DDRD = 0xFF;
   while(1) {
     lcd_cmd(0xFF);
     _delay_ms(100);
     lcd_cmd(0x00);
   }
}
```

However, the program below does exactly the same as your code (as far as you actually shared it with us), but is a lot shorter:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char data_cmd)
{
        PORTD = data_cmd;
        _delay_ms(800);
}

int main() {
   DDRD = 0xFF;
   while(1) {
     lcd_cmd(0xFF);
     _delay_ms(100);
     lcd_cmd(0x00);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in lcd_command()

```
lcd_data_pin = cmd & 0xF0;
```

Will always set d0-d3 to zero, as will

```
lcd_data_pin = (cmd << 4) & 0xF0;
```

because `& 0xF0` always results in a byte with the lower four bits clear -- d0 is the least significant bit of the port, d7 the most significant.

You may have meant to write:

```
lcd_data_pin = cmd & 0x0f; // send the low four bits
```

and

```
lcd_data_pin = (cmd >> 4) & 0x0f; // send the high four bits in the low four bits of D (the '&' is unnecessary as cmd is unsigned)
```

My code above also sets d4-d7 to zero, which I don't think matters in your application.

Comment: so I'll replace : lcd_data_pin = data_cmd; with : lcd_data_pin = cmd & 0x0f; // send the low four bits then lcd_data_pin = (cmd >> 4) & 0x0f; , is that what you mean ? thanks

Comment: so: void lcd_data(unsigned char data1)
{
     
    lcd_data_pin = data1 & 0xF0;;
    lcd_control(2);

 lcd_data_pin = (data1<< 4) & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(2);
    
        
}
 
void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd){
 
    lcd_data_pin = cmd & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(1);
 
    lcd_data_pin = (cmd << 4) & 0xF0;
    lcd_control(1);
 
 
}

Comment: Yes to your first comment -- I'm not sure what your second comment means. Feel free to accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: So far it's not working as expected, what do I miss here ?

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: Please have a look on the latest code...

Comment: Now you are transferring whole bytes rather than four bits at a time? I'm afraid I don't know enough about what you are trying to do to help.

Answer (score -1):

Set M103C fuse bit on ISP programmer to 0 and it will fix the issue,

thanks for any replies.

Comment: You should explain in more detail why this solved your problem. From what i can tell the compatibility mode does change nothing regarding PORTD.